# Comparison of Amazon S3, Amazon Athena, and Amazon Athena with partitioning

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, partitioning, amazon-athena

I wanted to know the performance improvement when we use Amazon Athena without partitioning and with partitioning. I know for sure that Athena with partitioning is much better than Athena. But does Athena without partitioning give any improvement over Amazon S3?

Comment: What do you mean by "does Athena without partitioning give any improvement over Amazon S3"? Amazon S3 is just a storage service, it does not directly compare with Amazon Athena. Or are you referring to S3 Select?

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning separates data files into separate directories. If the column used for partitioning is part of a query's `WHERE` clause, it allows Athena to skip-over directories that do not contain relevant data. This is highly effective at improve query performance (and lowering cost) because it reduces the need for disk access and memory.

There are several ways to improve the performance of Amazon Athena:

- **Store data in a columnar format**, such as Parquet. This allows Athena to go directly to specific columns without having to read all columns in a wide table. (This is similar to Amazon Redshift.)
- **Compress data** (eg using Snappy compression) to reduce the amount of data that needs to be read from disk. This also reduces the cost of queries since they are charged based on the amount of data read from disk. (Instant savings!)
- **Partition data** to completely skip-over input files when the partition key is used in a query's `WHERE` clause

For some examples of these benefits, see: [Analyzing Data in S3 using Amazon Athena | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyzing-data-in-s3-using-amazon-athena/)